# Http Request Hangs Client Side

Tags: web-server

We've run a website for several years with thousands of visitors. Very rarely the following problem happens to a certain group of users:

A certain user of that group makes a client side action on his browser (submits a form with POST) and waits for the server response. The page hangs on every third or fourth http request.

We monitored the server and saw that the request does not reach the Tomcat Application.

We asked the user to change the browser, clean the cache, try different hours and turn off the anti-virus program. Nothing helped. We asked the same user to use another computer on the same WIFI network and the issue did NOT appear on the other computer.

So, we can conclude that the issue is related to his specific PC, but since we had several users complaining about the issue we would like to narrow down the problem.

Did anyone have similar issues or know how we can help this group of users? Monitor on client side?

Comment: A packet capture on both the server and the client would help.

Comment: Basically before submitting the form for the first time a function is called after 5 seconds (with setTimeout) that checks if the page was not reloaded and still exists. If it is still not re-loaded it re-submits the form. Result of this JS: Once the system hangs, we see that the signal does NOT arrive at the server.More interestingly however is that although the javascript that executes works fine the re-submit of the form still does not work. We call this for a second time after 5 seconds: document.formNAME.submit() And nothing happens! Any idea?